# MVC Model property works intermittently with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, parameters

I have a pretty basic MVC application and I am using a little bit of jQuery/JavaScript in it.
I am passing a Model parameter of type string into a function call.  It works with some input but not others and I am wondering why and if it is any of the characters in the string.

Here are my functions:

```
//In the View
 $().ready(function () {
      alert(@Model.PartNumber);  // Returns nothing on second input value below
      LoadMenus(@Model.PartNumber);
});

// In an external js file referenced in _layout.cshtml
LoadMenus(partNumber){
     alert(partNumber) // Returns nothing on my second value from below
     $('#something').append('<a href="/MyController/Part?partNumber=' + partNumber + '"><div class="col-12 sidebar-link">Part</div></a>');
...
}
```

These are two of the values that I have used:

'**100226**' and the function is executed successfully, loading my menu

'**5237HES-06**' and the function doesn't execute

I have put console log and alert statements to see what gets loaded and what doesn't.  No JS alerts are triggered in the jquery or javascript functions.

Please shed some light.  Hopefully something silly that I am overlooking.

Comment: Use quotes around the value if it could be alphanumeric. `LoadMenus("@Model.PartNumber")`.

Comment: Thanks that was it